# How to enable cache in ORDS?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ords, oracle-rest-data-services

I have ORDS deployed on a windows machine behind an Oracle Apex application.

I would like to enable cache on ORDS. I tried the following but nothing is happening. ORDS is not caching anything and the cache directory specified in the configuration file is always empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Saved on Thu Feb 10 03:45:48 CET 2022</comment>
<entry key="cache.caching">true</entry>
<entry key="cache.directory">C:\02-Temp\ORDS-Cache</entry>
<entry key="cache.duration">days</entry>
<entry key="cache.expiration">7</entry>
<entry key="cache.maxEntries">500</entry>
<entry key="cache.monitorInterval">60</entry>
<entry key="cache.procedureNameList">*.*</entry>
<entry key="cache.type">lru</entry>
<entry key="database.api.enabled">true</entry>
<entry key="db.connectionType">basic</entry>
<entry key="db.hostname">hostname</entry>
<entry key="db.port">1521</entry>
<entry key="db.sid">XE</entry>
<entry key="debug.debugger">false</entry>
<entry key="debug.printDebugToScreen">false</entry>
<entry key="error.keepErrorMessages">true</entry>
<entry key="error.maxEntries">50</entry>
<entry key="feature.sdw">true</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.DriverType">thin</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.InactivityTimeout">300</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.InitialLimit">5</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.MaxConnectionReuseCount">100000</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.MaxLimit">30</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.MaxStatementsLimit">100000</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.MinLimit">5</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.statementTimeout">900</entry>
<entry key="log.logging">false</entry>
<entry key="log.maxEntries">30</entry>
<entry key="misc.compress">true</entry>
<entry key="misc.defaultPage">apex</entry>
<entry key="restEnabledSql.active">true</entry>
<entry key="security.disableDefaultExclusionList">false</entry>
<entry key="security.maxEntries">2000</entry> 
<entry key="security.requestValidationFunction">wwv_flow_epg_include_modules.authorize</entry>
<entry key="security.validationFunctionType">plsql</entry>
</properties>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: How is ORDS deployed? Is it standalone Jetty? Or using Webtier or Tomcat?

Comment: @EJEgyed ORDS is deployed using Tomcat. Do you have any idea please?

Comment: What information are you expecting to be cached? In the documentation for the latest version of ORDS (currently 21.4), none of the "cache" parameters you are specifying in your configuration file are valid configurable parameters. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.4/aelig/about-REST-configuration-files.html#GUID-37AA1468-DCB3-4D8B-868C-1910A0C04D68

Comment: Also see here for more information on the metadata caching: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.4/aelig/configuring-REST-data-services.html#GUID-4F6E4D0A-5A91-4A45-B2BB-75D0DF32865D